# Recovering from malware in the registry

Tags: malware

I'm a trainee who writes malware samples to later be tested.  A  basic piece I wrote in C++ kills explorer.exe, taskmgr.exe and repeats this every second.  I used a bit of code to add my application to the registry under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` so that it runs automatically when the test machine is started.
 Because the test machine is a VM, I can restore to the last snapshot and be on my merry way.  If this happened in a real world situation, how would one fix this problem?  Killing explorer and task manager leaves the user with only the desktop with no icons to look at.  I know Windows 7 will do a system restore before the boot but is this true for XP?  BIOS?  Or would they have to try and reinstall Windows cleanly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Microsoft's documentation about [run keys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314866) on Windows XP, it is stated that:

> By default, Run keys are ignored when the computer starts in Safe mode. Under the RunOnce keys, you can prefix a value name with an asterisk (*) to force the associated program to run even in Safe mode.

If not added under RunOnce with the force character, one could start in Safe mode and remove the key.

Comment: And if he adds the force character, the user is doomed?

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, it seems so. One user suggested to hit Win+R command, which lets you open an application, file or folder but it is dependent of the explorer.exe process.